webkit2gtk-4.0: How to load URI with TLS test certificate?
I'm using the example from here:-
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/WebKitGtk/ProgrammingGuide/Tutorial
which works fine using the given URI
But I want to use to a test site such as https://192.168.0.1
which has a test certificate.
// Load a web page into the browser instance
webkit_web_view_load_uri(webView, "https://192.168.0.1:300/");

How do I tell webkit2gtk-4.0 to ignore TLS errors
